# ViewPager using WindowManager

Tags: android

I am using WindowMananger to show a view on screen pretty much like what Facebook Messenger does with ChatHeads. It works fine for simple views but I have a trouble adding something like a viewpager. Can anyone help me how to add a viewpager like UI using WindowManager.

Here is a sample of code :

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
//returns a list of fragments
List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
mMyAdapter = new MyAdapter(*--GET FRAGMENT MANAGER--*, fragments);
viewPager.setAdapter(mMyAdapter);
```

The problem is how to get the fragment manager because the WindowManager is used from a Service and not an Activity

I followed the following tutorial : http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

Comment: Create layout that contains this `View Pager` and then inflated that layout in one `View` and then add that `View` into `Window Manager`

Comment: Can you please check out the edited version